# Echo null values in PHP

Tags: php

If we are do not define variable, we get notice, for example

```
<?php 
echo $a;
```

But if set null, we get empty string?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/602702f85a54ec4b42bfff22ca25127c4a4c9ace

```
<?php
$a = null;
echo $a;


$str = DB::find()->select('name')->where(['id' => 1])->one(); //returns null or string name

echo $str;
```

Is it normal practice use this approach for returned values from DB or some function or this is undocumented feature?

Or better handle vars like this?

```
<?php
echo $a ?: '';
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't null and an empty string the same thing visually? Nothing to see. So does this really matter?

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Please clarify that first.

Comment: `strval(NULL) === ""`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a feature known as "[type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)", where when a function is called on some data that is unsupported, PHP will try to convert the data to a usable format. For example, `echo 1234;` will output `1234`, rather than throwing an error (as `1234` is not a string).

Now, `null` is type juggled to the empty string, as it's probably the most logical thing for it to convert to (`null` representing the concept of nothing). This behaviour is defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting), under the converting to string section.

Comment: Thanks for "here" link. I googled it but not found match, only similar questions on stackoverflow :)